# Convert mp3 from mono to stereo using Lame

Tags: mp3, stereo, mono, lame

An application requires that the mp3 files it receives are encoded with 2 channels (stereo), but the original files have only 1 channel (mono).
We use Lame for conversion, but i fail to make it clone the mono channel and create a fake stereo.

```
lame.exe -m j mono.mp3 stereo.mp3
```

`-m d` or `-m s` doesn't seem to work either. Is it possible to do this with lame?

Comment: Do you have to just use LAME for this, or would you be willing to use Audacity?

Comment: Lame is called from within another application as a shell command. Audacity hasn't been considered as I thought it didn't have a useful command line interface. I surely may reconsider!

Comment: Oh, well, as far as I know, it doesn't have a command line interface. That's what I was wondering: why you needed to use LAME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to my own question is: *No - it is not possible with lame*

My work-around solution is to use the command-line tool `sox` and do the channel duplication prior to mp3-conversion:

```
sox mono.wav -c 2 stereo.wav
```

Then afterwards use lame:

```
lame -m j stereo.wav stereo.mp3
```

Comment: well there's such thing as joint stereo which you basically used in here, which is actually means you dublicate mono channel.

Comment: @holms Yes, that is what I use. The `-m j` will create a joint stereo, but as far as I know, it is not really a duplicate but rather encoding of the difference between the channels. And.. well.. since there is no difference in a duplicate, the added file size should be insignificant :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with ffmpeg.
Here is the command I used for mono mp3 files with 11025 Hz sampling rate and 40 kbps bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i mono.mp3 -ac 2 -ab 96000 -ar 22050 stereo.mp3
```

Comment: That worked. They still put "Mono" in the INFO Tag, though, but otherwise I got the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lame for this. With mono wav input, just use `-m s` as lame option. 
Using otherwise default lame options the output will be (simple) stereo.

EDIT: I was wrong! The original posters answer was correct: When the input wav is mono, you cannot get lame to make it stereo with `-m s`.

Comment: Note that with a mono wav file as input, lame outputs joint stereo as default, unless you specify something else.

Comment: this was also wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LAME Documentation](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE) @Modes I would try "-m d". You should also consider to double your bitrate, because it is shared by two channels now, not one.

Comment: As I mentioned, `-m d` and `-m s` didn't work either (or `-m f` for that matter). It seems lame ignores it and creates a single-channel file nontheless. Double bitrate is a good suggestion :)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that m( `-m i` doesn't work, too? there seems to be no option to assign each channel a input file...

Comment: But the idea of using the same file twice for each channel is a good one. It would be one way to solve it for sure. I am also looking into it.